# Conditional format duplicate values and format entire row

Tags: excel, formatting

I understand how to using conditional formatting to find duplicate values in a column. I also understand how to use a formula in conditional formatting to highlight multiple cells in a row. What I can't figure out is how to combine the two.

For example, is it possible to detect duplicate values in column A, and then format the affected row based on the detection of the duplicate value in A only?

Comment: its not clear which column or columns you'd like to highlight!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use absolute coordinates instead of relative ones.

ex. use the following conditional formula:

```
=COUNTIF($A:$A,$A1)>1
```

and apply it to the desire range (ex.: `=$A$1:$F$30`)

Comment: That works perfectly. Thanks

Comment: @hunterman - If my answer works for you, then please mark it as correct so others know your problem has been resolved